# You have been disconnected from the server

Tags: mysql, azerothcore

I followed the guide on azerothcore.org to install the server.  When I launch the `authserver.exe` and `worldserver.exe`, everything seems to work fine.  I can see in MySQL Workbench that acore is connecting to the database.  When I open a client that the realmlist is set to `127.0.0.1` and enter my credentials that were created via worldserver, I get the message:

> You have been disconnected from the server

I can display the config files if requested, the database was set up following the guide as well.

I've included both the server.log and the auth.log

```
AzerothCore rev. b3e37226745a 2023-01-16 17:24:28 +0000 (master branch) (Win64, RelWithDebInfo, Static) (authserver)
<Ctrl-C> to stop.

   █████╗ ███████╗███████╗██████╗  ██████╗ ████████╗██╗  ██╗
  ██╔══██╗╚══███╔╝██╔════╝██╔══██╗██╔═══██╗╚══██╔══╝██║  ██║
  ███████║  ███╔╝ █████╗  ██████╔╝██║   ██║   ██║   ███████║
  ██╔══██║ ███╔╝  ██╔══╝  ██╔══██╗██║   ██║   ██║   ██╔══██║
  ██║  ██║███████╗███████╗██║  ██║╚██████╔╝   ██║   ██║  ██║
  ╚═╝  ╚═╝╚══════╝╚══════╝╚═╝  ╚═╝ ╚═════╝    ╚═╝   ╚═╝  ╚═╝
                                 ██████╗ ██████╗ ██████╗ ███████╗
                                ██╔════╝██╔═══██╗██╔══██╗██╔════╝
                                ██║     ██║   ██║██████╔╝█████╗
                                ██║     ██║   ██║██╔══██╗██╔══╝
                                ╚██████╗╚██████╔╝██║  ██║███████╗
                                 ╚═════╝ ╚═════╝ ╚═╝  ╚═╝╚══════╝

     AzerothCore 3.3.5a  -  www.azerothcore.org

> Using configuration file       configs/authserver.conf.dist
> Using SSL version:             OpenSSL 1.1.1s  1 Nov 2022 (library: OpenSSL 1.1.1s  1 Nov 2022)
> Using Boost version:           1.81.0
 
Opening DatabasePool 'acore_auth'. Asynchronous connections: 1, synchronous connections: 1.
MySQL client library: 8.0.32
MySQL server ver: 8.0.32 
Connected to MySQL database at 127.0.0.1
MySQL client library: 8.0.32
MySQL server ver: 8.0.32 
Connected to MySQL database at 127.0.0.1
DatabasePool 'acore_auth' opened successfully. 2 total connections running.
 
Updating Auth database...
>> Auth database is up-to-date! Containing 1 new and 31 archived updates.
 
Started auth database connection pool.
Loading IP Location Database...
 
Added realm "AzerothCore" at 127.0.0.1:8085.
```

```
AzerothCore rev. b3e37226745a 2023-01-16 17:24:28 +0000 (master branch) (Win64, RelWithDebInfo, Static) (worldserver-daemon)
<Ctrl-C> to stop.

   █████╗ ███████╗███████╗██████╗  ██████╗ ████████╗██╗  ██╗
  ██╔══██╗╚══███╔╝██╔════╝██╔══██╗██╔═══██╗╚══██╔══╝██║  ██║
  ███████║  ███╔╝ █████╗  ██████╔╝██║   ██║   ██║   ███████║
  ██╔══██║ ███╔╝  ██╔══╝  ██╔══██╗██║   ██║   ██║   ██╔══██║
  ██║  ██║███████╗███████╗██║  ██║╚██████╔╝   ██║   ██║  ██║
  ╚═╝  ╚═╝╚══════╝╚══════╝╚═╝  ╚═╝ ╚═════╝    ╚═╝   ╚═╝  ╚═╝
                                 ██████╗ ██████╗ ██████╗ ███████╗
                                ██╔════╝██╔═══██╗██╔══██╗██╔════╝
                                ██║     ██║   ██║██████╔╝█████╗
                                ██║     ██║   ██║██╔══██╗██╔══╝
                                ╚██████╗╚██████╔╝██║  ██║███████╗
                                 ╚═════╝ ╚═════╝ ╚═╝  ╚═╝╚══════╝

     AzerothCore 3.3.5a  -  www.azerothcore.org

> Using configuration file       configs/worldserver.conf.dist
> Using SSL version:             OpenSSL 1.1.1s  1 Nov 2022 (library: OpenSSL 1.1.1s  1 Nov 2022)
> Using Boost version:           1.81.0
 
Process priority class set to HIGH
Initializing Scripts...
> Loading C++ scripts
 
Opening DatabasePool 'acore_auth'. Asynchronous connections: 1, synchronous connections: 1.
DatabasePool 'acore_auth' opened successfully. 2 total connections running.
 
Opening DatabasePool 'acore_characters'. Asynchronous connections: 1, synchronous connections: 2.
DatabasePool 'acore_characters' opened successfully. 3 total connections running.
 
Opening DatabasePool 'acore_world'. Asynchronous connections: 1, synchronous connections: 1.
DatabasePool 'acore_world' opened successfully. 2 total connections running.
 
Updating Auth database...
>> Auth database is up-to-date! Containing 1 new and 31 archived updates.
 
Updating Character database...
>> Character database is up-to-date! Containing 3 new and 54 archived updates.
 
Updating World database...
>> World database is up-to-date! Containing 458 new and 3160 archived updates.
 
Loading World Information...
> RealmID:              1
> Version DB world:     ACDB 335.8-dev
Will clear `logs` table of entries older than 1209600 seconds every 10 minutes.
Using DataDir F:\AzerothCore_MainFolder\AzerothCore_Source\Build\bin\RelWithDebInfo\Data/
WORLD: VMap support included. LineOfSight:true, getHeight:true, indoorCheck:true PetLOS:true
 
Loading Acore Strings...
>> Loaded 1153 Acore Strings in 7 ms
 
Initialize Data Stores...
>> Initialized 107 Data Stores in 378 ms
 
Using enUS DBC Locale As Default. All Available DBC locales: enUS 
 
>> Loading Cinematic Camera files
>> Loaded 14 Cinematic Waypoint Sets in 1 ms
 
Loading IP Location Database...
 
Loading Game Graveyard...
>> Loaded 685 Graveyard in 4 ms
 
Initializing PlayerDump Tables...
>> Initialized Tables For PlayerDump in 28 ms.
 
Loading SpellInfo Store...
>> Loaded Spell Custom Attributes in 28 ms
 
Loading SpellInfo Data Corrections...
>> Loading spell dbc data corrections  in 4 ms
 
Loading Spell Rank Data...
>> Loaded 3502 spell rank records in 10 ms
 
Loading Spell Specific And Aura State...
>> Loaded Spell Specific And Aura State in 6 ms
 
Loading SkillLineAbilityMultiMap Data...
>> Loaded 10219 SkillLineAbility MultiMap Data in 1 ms
 
Loading SpellInfo Custom Attributes...
>> Loaded 263 spell custom attributes from DB in 1 ms
>> Loaded SpellInfo Custom Attributes in 22 ms
 
Loading GameObject Models...
>> Loaded 2324 GameObject Models in 1 ms
 
Loading Script Names...
>> Loaded 2844 ScriptNames in 963 ms
 
Loading Instance Template...
>> Loaded 85 Instance Templates in 0 ms
 
Loading Instance Saved Gameobject State Data...
Loading Character Cache...
No character name data loaded, empty query!
Loading Instances...
>> Loaded Instances And Binds in 4 ms
 
Loading Broadcast Texts...
>> Loaded 73039 Broadcast Texts in 378 ms
>> Loaded 583570 Broadcast Text Locales in 1018 ms
 
Loading Localization Strings...
>> Loaded 27290 Creature Locale Strings in 865 ms
>> Loaded 21503 Gameobject Locale Strings in 623 ms
>> Loaded 46096 Item Locale Strings in 432 ms
>> Loaded 2481 Item Set Name Locale Strings in 60 ms
>> Loaded 9461 Quest Locale Strings in 228 ms
>> Loaded 14739 Quest Offer Reward Locale Strings in 75 ms
>> Loaded 14739 Quest Request Items Locale Strings in 53 ms
>> Loaded 8365 Npc Text Locale Strings in 74 ms
>> Loaded 1974 Page Text Locale Strings in 36 ms
>> Loaded 5039 Gossip Menu Option Locale Strings in 61 ms
>> Loaded 453 Points Of Interest Locale Strings in 4 ms
>> Localization Strings loaded in 2517 ms
 
Loading Page Texts...
>> Loaded 1946 Page Texts in 10 ms
 
Loading Game Object Templates...
>> Loaded 21579 Game Object Templates in 94 ms
 
Loading Game Object Template Addons...
>> Loaded 21493 Game Object Template Addons in 52 ms
 
Loading Transport Templates...
>> Loaded 30 Transport Templates in 45 ms
 
Loading Spell Required Data...
>> Loaded 50 Spell Required Records in 1 ms
 
Loading Spell Group Types...
>> Loaded 356 Spell Group Definitions in 2 ms
 
Loading Spell Learn Skills...
>> Loaded 103 Spell Learn Skills From DBC in 1 ms
 
Loading Spell Proc Event Conditions...
>> Loaded 813 Extra Spell Proc Event Conditions in 3 ms
 
Loading Spell Proc Conditions and Data...
>> Loaded 0 Spell Proc Conditions And Data. DB table `spell_proc` Is Empty.
 
Loading Spell Bonus Data...
>> Loaded 1270 Extra Spell Bonus Data in 7 ms
 
Loading Aggro Spells Definitions...
>> Loaded 107 SpellThreatEntries in 1 ms
 
Loading Mixology Bonuses...
>> Loaded 21 Mixology Bonuses in 1 ms
 
Loading Spell Group Stack Rules...
>> Loaded 37 Spell Group Stack Rules in 1 ms
 
Loading NPC Texts...
>> Loaded 8348 Npc Texts in 89 ms
 
Loading Enchant Spells Proc Datas...
>> Loaded 42 Enchant Proc Data Definitions in 1 ms
 
Loading Item Random Enchantments Table...
>> Loaded 28606 Item Enchantment Definitions in 61 ms
 
Loading Disables
>> Loaded 905 Disables in 4 ms
 
Loading Items...
>> Loaded 46096 Item Templates in 592 ms
 
Loading Item Set Names...
>> Loaded 2481 Item Set Names in 11 ms
 
Loading Creature Model Based Info Data...
>> Loaded 24143 Creature Model Based Info in 58 ms
 
Loading Creature Templates...
>> Loaded 2225 Creature Template Resistances in 2 ms
 
>> Loaded 9511 Creature Template Spells in 9 ms
 
>> Loaded 29953 Creature Definitions in 356 ms
 
Loading Equipment Templates...
>> Loaded 10761 Equipment Templates in 26 ms
 
Loading Creature Template Addons...
>> Loaded 11819 Creature Template Addons in 34 ms
 
Loading Reputation Reward Rates...
>> Loaded 14 Reputation Reward Rate in 1 ms
 
Loading Creature Reputation OnKill Data...
>> Loaded 2054 Creature Award Reputation Definitions in 8 ms
 
Loading Reputation Spillover Data...
>> Loaded 26 Reputation Spillover Template in 1 ms
 
Loading Points Of Interest Data...
>> Loaded 463 Points of Interest Definitions in 3 ms
 
Loading Creature Base Stats...
>> Loaded 400 Creature Base Stats in 5 ms
 
Loading Creature Data...
>> Loaded 147704 Creatures in 1175 ms
 
Loading Temporary Summon Data...
>> Loaded 608 Temporary Summons in 3 ms
 
Loading Pet Levelup Spells...
>> Loaded 993 Pet Levelup And Default Spells For 39 Families in 3 ms
 
Loading Pet default Spells additional to Levelup Spells...
>> Loaded Addition Spells For 112 Pet Spell Data Entries in 1 ms
 
Loading Summonable Creature Templates...
>> Loaded 424 Summonable Creature emplates in 3 ms
 
Loading Creature Addon Data...
>> Loaded 35002 Creature Addons in 99 ms
 
Loading Creature Movement Overrides...
>> Loaded 11 Movement Overrides in 1 ms
 
Loading Gameobject Data...
>> Loaded 85775 Gameobjects in 608 ms
 
Loading GameObject Addon Data...
>> Loaded 32 Gameobject Addons in 2 ms
 
Loading GameObject Quest Items...
>> Loaded 862 Gameobject Quest Items in 2 ms
 
Loading Creature Quest Items...
>> Loaded 4416 Creature Quest Items in 10 ms
 
Loading Creature Linked Respawn...
>> Loaded 5749 Linked Respawns In 16 ms
 
Loading Weather Data...
>> Loaded 35 Weather Definitions in 0 ms
 
Loading Quests...
>> Loaded 9464 Quests Definitions in 258 ms
 
Checking Quest Disables
>> Checked 693 Quest Disables in 0 ms
 
Loading Quest POI
>> Loaded 18771 Quest POI definitions in 182 ms
 
Loading Quests Starters and Enders...
Loading GO Start Quest Data...
>> Loaded 455 Quest Relations From gameobject_queststarter in 2 ms
 
Loading GO End Quest Data...
>> Loaded 457 Quest Relations From gameobject_questender in 2 ms
 
Loading Creature Start Quest Data...
>> Loaded 7497 Quest Relations From creature_queststarter in 9 ms
 
Loading Creature End Quest Data...
>> Loaded 7898 Quest Relations From creature_questender in 9 ms
 
Loading Quest Greetings...
>> Loaded 206 quest_greeting in 2 ms
 
Loading Quest Greeting Locales...
>> Loaded 3 quest greeting Locale Strings in 1 ms
 
Loading Quest Money Rewards...
>> Loaded 800 Quest Money Rewards in 1 ms
 
Loading Objects Pooling Data...
>> Loaded 4960 Objects Pools In 20 ms
 
Loading Creatures Pooling Data...
>> Loaded 1437 Creatures In Pools in 7 ms
 
Loading Gameobjects Pooling Data...
>> Loaded 29111 Gameobjects In Pools in 120 ms
 
Loading Mother Pooling Data...
>> Loaded 3690 Pools In Mother Pools in 17 ms
 
Loading Quest Pooling Data...
>> Loaded 162 Quests In Pools in 1 ms
 
Starting Objects Pooling System...
 
Loading Game Event Data...
>> Loaded 156 Holiday Dates in 1 ms
>> Loaded 83 Game Events in 0 ms
 
Loading Game Event Saves Data...
>> Loaded 0 Game Event Saves In Game Events. DB Table `game_event_save` Is Empty.
 
Loading Game Event Prerequisite Data...
>> Loaded 0 Game Rvent Prerequisites in Game Events. DB Table `game_event_prerequisite` Is Empty.
 
Loading Game Event Creature Data...
>> Loaded 8817 Creatures In Game Events in 4 ms
 
Loading Game Event GO Data...
>> Loaded 21709 Gameobjects In Game Events in 10 ms
 
Loading Game Event Model/Equipment Change Data...
>> Loaded 0 Model/Equipment Changes In Game Events. DB Table `game_event_model_equip` Is Empty.
 
Loading Game Event Quest Data...
>> Loaded 215 Quests Additions In Game Events in 1 ms
 
Loading Game Event GO Quest Data...
>> Loaded 78 Quests Additions In Game Events in 1 ms
 
Loading Game Event Quest Condition Data...
>> Loaded 0 quest event Conditions In Game Events. DB Table `game_event_quest_condition` Is Empty.
 
Loading Game Event Condition Data...
>> Loaded 0 Conditions In Game Events. DB table `game_event_condition` Is Empty.
 
Loading Game Event Condition Save Data...
>> Loaded 0 Condition Saves In Game Events. DB Table `game_event_condition_save` Is Empty.
 
Loading Game Event NPCflag Data...
>> Loaded 5 Npcflags In Game Events In 1 ms
 
Loading Game Event Seasonal Quest Relations...
>> Loaded 690 Quests Additions In Game Events in 1 ms
 
Loading Game Event Vendor Additions Data...
>> Loaded 14 Vendor Additions In Game Events in 2 ms
 
Loading Game Event Battleground Data...
>> Loaded 6 Battleground Holidays In Game Events in 1 ms
 
Loading Game Event Pool Data...
>> Loaded 8 Pools For Game Events in 0 ms
 
Loading UNIT_NPC_FLAG_SPELLCLICK Data...
>> Loaded 330 Spellclick Definitions in 3 ms
 
Loading Vehicle Template Accessories...
>> Loaded 193 Vehicle Template Accessories in 2 ms
 
Loading Vehicle Accessories...
>> Loaded 0 Vehicle Accessories in 1 ms
 
Loading SpellArea Data...
>> Using ICC Buff Horde: 73822
>> Using ICC Buff Alliance: 73828
>> Loaded 699 Spell Area Requirements in 4 ms
 
Loading Area Trigger Definitions
>> Loaded 1217 Area Trigger Definitions in 4 ms
 
Loading Area Trigger Teleport Definitions...
>> Loaded 273 Area Trigger Teleport Definitions in 2 ms
 
Loading Access Requirements...
>> Loaded 121 Rows From dungeon_access_template And 35 Rows From dungeon_access_requirements in 14 ms
 
Loading Quest Area Triggers...
>> Loaded 59 Quest Trigger Points in 1 ms
 
Loading Tavern Area Triggers...
>> Loaded 113 Tavern Triggers in 2 ms
 
Loading AreaTrigger Script Names...
>> Loaded 138 Areatrigger Scripts in 0 ms
 
Loading LFG Entrance Positions...
>> Loaded 22 LFG Entrance Positions in 1 ms
 
Loading Dungeon Boss Data...
>> Loaded 612 Instance Encounters in 3 ms
 
Loading LFG Rewards...
>> Loaded 15 LFG Dungeon Rewards in 1 ms
 
Loading Graveyard-Zone Links...
>> Loaded 704 Graveyard-Zone Links in 3 ms
 
Loading Spell Pet Auras...
>> Loaded 49 Spell Pet Auras in 1 ms
 
Loading Spell Target Coordinates...
>> Loaded 667 Spell Teleport Coordinates in 3 ms
 
Loading Enchant Custom Attributes...
>> Loaded 47 Custom Enchant Attributes in 1 ms
 
Loading linked Spells...
>> Loaded 578 Linked Spells in 2 ms
 
Loading Player Create Data...
>> Loaded 62 Player Create Definitions in 1 ms
 
Loading Player Create Items Data...
>> Loaded 1 Custom Player Create Items in 2 ms
 
Loading Player Create Skill Data...
>> Loaded 1103 Player Create Skills in 1 ms
 
Loading Player Create Spell Data...
>> Loaded 0 player create spells. DB table `playercreateinfo_spell_custom` is empty.
Loading Player Create Cast Spell Data...
>> Loaded 19 Player Create Cast Spells in 1 ms
 
Loading Player Create Action Data...
>> Loaded 283 Player Create Actions in 2 ms
 
Loading Player Create Level HP/Mana Data...
>> Loaded 800 Level Health/Mana Definitions in 3 ms
 
Loading Player Create Level Stats Data...
>> Loaded 800 Level Stats Definitions in 4 ms
 
Loading Player Create XP Data...
>> Loaded 79 Xp For Level Definitions in 0 ms
 
Loading Exploration BaseXP Data...
>> Loaded 80 BaseXP Definitions in 1 ms
 
Loading Pet Name Parts...
>> Loaded 313 Pet Name Parts in 1 ms
 
Loading The Max Pet Number...
>> Loaded The Max Pet Number: 0 in 1 ms
 
Loading Pet Level Stats...
>> Loaded 2720 Level Pet Stats Definitions in 7 ms
 
Loading Player Level Dependent Mail Rewards...
>> Loaded 24 Level Dependent Mail Rewards in 1 ms
 
Load Mail Server Template...
 
Loading Creature Loot Templates...
>> Loaded 329594 Creature Loot Templates in 1471 ms
 
Loading Fishing Loot Templates...
>> Loaded 254 Fishing Loot Templates in 3 ms
 
Loading Gameobject Loot Templates...
>> Loaded 17993 Gameobject Loot Templates in 81 ms
 
Loading Item Loot Templates...
>> Loaded 5001 item loot templates in 18 ms
 
Loading Mail Loot Templates...
>> Loaded 105 mail loot templates in 1 ms
 
Loading Milling Loot Templates...
>> Loaded 45 milling loot templates in 4 ms
 
Loading Pickpocketing Loot Templates...
>> Loaded 10996 pickpocketing loot templates in 34 ms
 
Loading Skinning Loot Templates...
>> Loaded 1880 skinning loot templates in 7 ms
 
Loading Disenchanting Loot Templates...
>> Loaded 124 disenchanting loot templates in 3 ms
 
Loading Prospecting Loot Templates...
>> Loaded 37 prospecting loot templates in 2 ms
 
Loading Spell Loot Templates...
>> Loaded 163 spell loot templates in 3 ms
 
Loading Reference Loot Templates...
>> Loaded refence loot templates in 54 ms
 
Loading Player Loot Templates...
>> Loaded 20 player loot templates in 2 ms
 
Loading Skill Discovery Table...
>> Loaded 347 skill discovery definitions in 3 ms
 
Loading Skill Extra Item Table...
>> Loaded 226 spell specialization definitions in 1 ms
 
Loading Skill Perfection Data Table...
>> Loaded 72 spell perfection definitions in 1 ms
 
Loading Skill Fishing Base Level Requirements...
>> Loaded 94 areas for fishing base skill level in 1 ms
 
Loading Achievements...
>> Loaded 43 achievement references in 0 ms
 
Loading Achievement Criteria Lists...
>> Loaded 7655 achievement criteria in 2 ms
 
Loading Achievement Criteria Data...
>> Loaded 2789 additional achievement criteria data in 7 ms
 
Loading Achievement Rewards...
>> Loaded 103 achievement rewards in 1 ms
 
Loading Achievement Reward Locales...
>> Loaded 103 Achievement Reward Locale Strings in 1 ms
 
Loading Completed Achievements...
>> Loaded 0 completed achievements. DB table `character_achievement` is empty.
 
Loading Item Auctions...
>> Loaded 0 auction items. DB table `auctionhouse` or `item_instance` is empty!
 
Loading Auctions...
>> Loaded 0 auctions. DB table `auctionhouse` is empty.
 
Loading Guilds Definitions...
>> Loaded 0 guild definitions. DB table `guild` is empty.
 
Loading Guild Ranks...
>> Loaded 0 guild ranks. DB table `guild_rank` is empty.
 
Loading Guild Members...
>> Loaded 0 guild members. DB table `guild_member` is empty.
 
Loading Bank Tab Rights...
>> Loaded 0 guild bank tab rights. DB table `guild_bank_right` is empty.
 
Loading Guild Event Logs...
>> Loaded 0 guild event logs. DB table `guild_eventlog` is empty.
 
Loading Guild Bank Event Logs...
>> Loaded 0 guild bank event logs. DB table `guild_bank_eventlog` is empty.
 
Loading Guild Bank Tabs...
>> Loaded 0 guild bank tabs. DB table `guild_bank_tab` is empty.
 
Filling bank tabs with items...
>> Loaded 0 guild bank tab items. DB table `guild_bank_item` or `item_instance` is empty.
 
Validating data of loaded guilds...
>> Validated data of loaded guilds in 0 ms
 
Loading ArenaTeams...
>> Loaded 0 arena teams. DB table `arena_team` is empty!
 
Loading Groups...
>> Loaded 0 group definitions. DB table `groups` is empty!
 
Loading Group Members...
>> Loaded 0 group members. DB table `group_member` is empty!
 
Loading ReservedNames...
>> Loaded 0 reserved player names. DB table `reserved_name` is empty!
 
Loading GameObjects for Quests...
>> Loaded 1820 GameObjects for quests in 1 ms
 
Loading BattleMasters...
>> Loaded 146 battlemaster entries in 2 ms
 
Loading GameTeleports...
>> Loaded 1491 GameTeleports in 8 ms
 
Loading Gossip Menu...
>> Loaded 5954 gossip_menu entries in 5 ms
 
Loading Gossip Menu Options...
>> Loaded 4485 gossip_menu_option entries in 26 ms
 
Loading Vendors...
>> Loaded 37672 Vendors in 93 ms
 
Loading Trainers...
>> Loaded 79232 Trainers in 253 ms
 
Loading Waypoints...
>> Loaded 135897 waypoints in 443 ms
 
Loading SmartAI Waypoints...
>> Loaded 611 SmartAI waypoint paths (total 11926 waypoints) in 52 ms
 
Loading Creature Formations...
>> Loaded 3854 Creatures In Formations in 11 ms
 
Loading World States...
>> Loaded 105 World States in 1 ms
 
Loading Conditions...
>> Loaded 14884 conditions in 75 ms
 
Loading Faction Change Achievement Pairs...
>> Loaded 124 faction change achievement pairs in 0 ms
 
Loading Faction Change Spell Pairs...
>> Loaded 113 faction change spell pairs in 1 ms
 
Loading Faction Change Item Pairs...
>> Loaded 1395 faction change item pairs in 1 ms
 
Loading Faction Change Reputation Pairs...
>> Loaded 15 faction change reputation pairs in 0 ms
 
Loading Faction Change Title Pairs...
>> Loaded 22 faction change title pairs in 1 ms
 
Loading Faction Change Quest Pairs...
>> Loaded 293 faction change quest pairs in 0 ms
 
Loading GM Tickets...
>> Loaded 0 GM tickets. DB table `gm_ticket` is empty!
Loading GM Surveys...
>> Loaded GM Survey count from database in 1 ms
 
Loading Client Addons...
>> Loaded 23 known addons in 1 ms
 
Deleting Invalid Mail Items...
 
Returning Old Mails...
 
Loading Autobroadcasts...
>> Loaded 0 autobroadcasts definitions. DB table `autobroadcast` is empty for this realm!
 
Loading spell_scripts...
>> Loaded 130 script definitions in 1 ms
 
Loading event_scripts...
>> Loaded 468 script definitions in 3 ms
 
Loading waypoint_scripts...
>> Loaded 589 script definitions in 2 ms
 
Loading Spell Script Names...
>> Loaded 2084 spell script names in 2 ms
 
Loading Creature Texts...
>> Loaded 18236 Creature Texts For 4005 Creatures in 89 ms
 
Loading Creature Text Locales...
>> Loaded 14051 Creature Text Locale in 35 ms
 
Loading Scripts...
Loading Script Waypoints For 65 Creature(s)...
>> Loaded 2388 Script Waypoint nodes in 13 ms
>> Loaded 2896 C++ scripts in 47 ms
 
Validating Spell Scripts...
>> Validated 2459 scripts in 5 ms
 
Loading SmartAI Scripts...
>> Loaded 12124 SmartAI scripts in 289 ms
 
Loading Calendar Data...
>> Loaded 0 calendar events
>> Loaded 0 calendar invites
 
Initializing SpellInfo Precomputed Data...
 
Initialize Commands...
Initialize Game Time and Timers
 
Starting Map System
 
Starting Game Event system...
 
Player::DeleteOldChars: Deleting all characters which have been deleted 30 days before...
 
Initializing Opcodes...
Starting Arena Season...
 
Arena Season 8 started...
 
Starting Battleground System
>> Loaded 13 battlegrounds in 0 ms
 
Starting Outdoor PvP System
>> Loaded 7 outdoor PvP definitions in 0 ms
 
Starting Battlefield System
Battlefield: Wintergrasp successfully initiated.
 
Loading Transports...
>> Spawned 20 continent motion transports in 186 ms
Loading Warden Checks...
>> Loaded 793 warden checks.
 
Loading Warden Action Overrides...
>> Loaded 1 warden action overrides.
 
Deleting Expired Bans...
Calculate Next Daily Quest Reset Time...
Calculate Next Weekly Quest Reset Time...
Calculate Next Monthly Quest Reset Time...
Calculate Random Battleground Reset Time...
Calculate Deletion Of Old Calendar Events Time...
Calculate Guild Cap Reset Time...
 
Load Petitions...
>> Loaded 0 Petitions!
 
Load Petition Signs...
>> Loaded 0 Petition signs!
 
Load Stored Loot Items...
>> Loaded 0 stored items!
 
Load Channel Rights...
>> Loaded 0 Channel Rights!
 
Load Channels...
>> Loaded 0 channels. DB table `channels` is empty.
 
WORLD: World Initialized In 0 Minutes 13 Seconds
 
AzerothCore rev. b3e37226745a 2023-01-16 17:24:28 +0000 (master branch) (Win64, RelWithDebInfo, Static) (worldserver-daemon) ready...
Starting up Auction House Listing thread...
```

I've reviewed the guide as well as the config files, to see if I missed anything.  I've recreated the database and ensured that the .exe's were connecting to MySQL.  Upon logging in, I get the disconnected message.  Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting from a client on the same machine as the server?

If not, please check the [networking](https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/networking) section of the wiki. You need to set your machine's IP in the realmlist table. Otherwise the authserver will tell the client to pass the connection to 127.0.0.1, which is 'localhost'. And localhost is obviously different on another computer.

Comment: yes, localhost for both server and client

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your realmlist.wtf file has the set portal set to your ip of the server location

Comment: set realmlist  127.0.0.1 is realmlist.wtf

Answer (score 0):

try restarting your PC.

if its not fixed maybe you have problem on your firewall or network it self. try resetting your network from: setting > network & internet > advanced network settings > Network reset

let us know if your problem solved!

Comment: Focus more on grammar and spelling mistakes